# Thomason resolution of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth quasi-projective scheme over a field $k$ and $G$ an algebraic group (also over $k$ not necessarily reductive) acting on $X$.

I the work of Thomason "Equivariant Resolution, Linearization, and
Hilbert’s Fourteenth Problem over Arbitrary Base Schemes" it is mentioned that every equivariant coherent sheaf has a finite resolution of equivariant vector bundles. I am searching for a reference for this classical fact.

Thanks in advance!